# Videos not uploading to s3 bucket in AWS from iOS device but works for android device, ionic 6

Tags: amazon-s3, ionic-framework

We have an ionic 6 app and we are using s3 bucket in AWS to save media files (images, videos, documents) using a signedURL, to upload them from our app.
For android device, it works well and uploads both images and videos to the s3 bucket.
For iOS devices, it uploads images but does not upload videos to the s3 bucket.

Are there some settings in the AWS s3 bucket that requires to be specified for iOS devices ?

The webpath (local file location) that we pass to AWS is different for android and iOS, because their file systems are different, can this be an issue ? (This is the only difference in the payload of our API for android and iOS devices)

Any help or direction is highly appreciated.

Tried using videos with different extensions but not affect.